# Multiple Facebook 'like' buttons using jQuery tabs

Tags: jquery, facebook, jquery-ui, tabs, facebook-like

I put a Facebook [like button](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like_button) button for each product I have in a jQuery tab.

I added the namespace on my [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) element:

```
<html lang="fr" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

I included the SDK JavaScript:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

The Facebook like button used is:

```
<fb:like send="false" width="90" show_faces="false" layout="button_count" href="http://www.google11.fr"></fb:like>
```

But it seems that 95% of time, it doesn't show the buttons.

For your information: I don't use Ajax. When I put the button in the default tab, it works well.

How do I fix this problem?